# What do I do with my downvoted question

Tags: discussion, downvotes

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175901/if-else-operator) has been answered well but down voted.  What should I do with it: close it, delete it, ignore it?

Comment: It has an upvoted answer. You can't delete it. So just ignore it.

Comment: Leave it and learn from it. Your question was probably downvoted because it lacks research effort. Next time, I'd consider searching around a bit more before you post a question.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I promise I searched around a lot more for that question than I did for the majority of other questions I have posed on SE. I think your response would be true if you said, "Your question was probably downvoted because users assumed it lacks research effort."

Comment: @fsmart: Or "your question was probably downvoted because it *does not show* any research effort." (Which is the very text on the downvote button, BTW.)  We can only go by what's posted.  And what's there makes me want to comment with "RTFM".  (Though admittedly, i don't know R.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even basic questions can be useful - you could always edit it and improve it.  Pad it out with an explanation of why you were confused by it in the first place, what you expected instead etc.  If it looks like you made an effort, no matter how trivial then it's less likely to be down voted further.

Otherwise flag it for moderator attention / close vote... if it's closed and eventually deleted - then you'll get your points back the next time the back-end does a recalculation.

Comment: It won't be auto-deleted even when closed, not with an answer with a positive score.